# Loop over dataframe to store multiple dataframe-subsets

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, subset, apply

I have a data.frame (df) with N users (rows) and i Items (cols) coded binary. 
From my basis df I would like to do different subsets to analyze and plot them. 
Using my created code below I always crashing R Studio and getting an error. 
So my question is what is wrong here? And how can I solve it? 
How can I optimize my code by using the apply-family to increase performance=?

**My expected output:**
A list with length(i) different data.frames of subsets of my basis df.

```
list <- c("1","2","3","4")
for (i in list) {
    assign(paste("datasub.",i,sep=""), subset(df, df[,i]==1))
}
```

Many thx for help!

Comment: Your elements of `list` are of type character, so perhaps try `df[,as.numeric(i)]==1` in your final brackets.

Comment: aaahh - thx a lot, works! But: how can I store my multiple data.frames in only one list? -> to reduce the number ob my objects in my environment

Comment: `lapply(list, function(i) subset(df, df[, as.numeric(i)]==1))` will produce a single list of the subsetted dfs.